# Json.Net serialization gives wrong property to custom converter

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this model that I want to serialize and deserialize using Json.Net:

```cs
public struct RangeOrValue
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public int Min { get; }
    public int Max { get; }
    public bool IsRange { get; }

    public RangeOrValue(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
        IsRange = true;
        Value = 0;
    }

    public RangeOrValue(int value)
    {
        Min = 0;
        Max = 0;
        Value = value;
        IsRange = false;
    }
}
```

I have a special requirement for serialization. If the first constructor is used, then the value should be serialized as `{ "Min": <min>, "Max": <max> }`.
But if the second constructor is used, then value should be serialized as `<value>`.

For example `new RangeOrValue(0, 10)` needs to be serialized as `{ "Min": 0, "Max": 10 }` and `new RangeOrValue(10)` needs to be serialized as `10`.

I wrote this custom converter to do this task:

```cs
public class RangeOrValueConverter : JsonConverter<RangeOrValue>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, RangeOrValue value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.IsRange)
        {
            // Range values are stored as objects
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("Min");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Min);
            writer.WritePropertyName("Max");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Max);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.Value);
        }
    }

    public override RangeOrValue ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, RangeOrValue existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        reader.Read();
        // If the type is range, then first token should be property name ("Min" property)
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
        {
            // Read min value
            int min = reader.ReadAsInt32() ?? 0;
            // Read next property name
            reader.Read(); 
            // Read max value
            int max = reader.ReadAsInt32() ?? 0;
            // Read object end
            reader.Read();
            return new RangeOrValue(min, max);
        }

        // Read simple int
        return new RangeOrValue(Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value));
    }
}
```

To test the functionality, I wrote this simple test:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class RangeOrValueConverterTest
{
    public class Model
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public RangeOrValue Value { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public RangeOrValue[] Values { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Serialization_Value()
    {
        var model = new Model
        {
            Value = new RangeOrValue(10),
            Values = new[] {new RangeOrValue(30), new RangeOrValue(40), new RangeOrValue(50),},
            Property1 = "P1",
            Property2 = "P2",
            Property3 = "P3"
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new RangeOrValueConverter());

        var deserializedModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json, new RangeOrValueConverter());

        Assert.AreEqual(model, deserializedModel);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, Object serializes successfully. But when it tries to deserialize it back, I receive this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Could not convert string to integer: P2. Path 'Property2', line 1, position 46.
```

The stack trace leads to line `int min = reader.ReadAsInt32() ?? 0;`.

I think I'm doing something wrong in converter that causes Json.Net to provide wrong values to the converter. But I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that, at the beginning of `ReadJson()`, you unconditionally call [`Read()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Read.htm) to advance the reader past the current token:

```
public override RangeOrValue ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, RangeOrValue existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    reader.Read();
```

However, if the current token is an integer corresponding to a `RangeOrValue` with a single value, then you have just skipped past that value, leaving the reader positioned on whatever comes next.  Instead you need to process the *current* value when that value is of type `JsonToken.Integer`.

That being said, there are several other possible issues with your converter, mostly related to the fact that you *assume* that the incoming JSON is in a particular format, rather than validating that fact:

- According to the [JSON standard](https://json.org/) an object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs* but `ReadJson()` assumes a specific property order.
- `ReadJson()` doesn't skip past or error on unknown properties.
- `ReadJson()` doesn't error on truncated files.
- `ReadJson()` doesn't error on unexpected token types (say, an array instead of an object or integer).
- If the JSON file contains comments (which are not included in the JSON standard but are supported by Json.NET) then `ReadJson()` will not handle this.
- The converter doesn't handle `Nullable<RangeOrValue>` members.

  Note that if you inherit from [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConverter.cs#L81), then you will have to write separate converters for `T` and `Nullable<T>`.  Thus, for structs, I think it's easier to inherit from the base class `JsonConverter`.

A `JsonConverter` that handles these issues would look something like the following:

```
public class RangeOrValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    const string MinName = "Min";
    const string MaxName = "Max";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(RangeOrValue) || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) == typeof(RangeOrValue);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var range = (RangeOrValue)value;
        if (range.IsRange)
        {
            // Range values are stored as objects
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(MinName);
            writer.WriteValue(range.Min);
            writer.WritePropertyName(MaxName);
            writer.WriteValue(range.Max);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(range.Value);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContent().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                // nullable RangeOrValue; return null.
                return null;  

            case JsonToken.Integer:
                return new RangeOrValue(reader.ValueAsInt32());

            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                int? min = null;
                int? max = null;
                var done = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    // Read the next token skipping comments if any
                    switch (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
                    {
                        case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                            var name = (string)reader.Value;
                            if (name.Equals(MinName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                // ReadAsInt32() reads the NEXT token as an Int32, thus advancing past the property name.
                                min = reader.ReadAsInt32();
                            else if (name.Equals(MaxName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                max = reader.ReadAsInt32();
                            else
                                // Unknown property name.  Skip past it and its value.
                                reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().Skip();
                            break;

                        case JsonToken.EndObject:
                            done = true;
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid token type {0} at path {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
                    }
                }
                if (max != null && min != null)
                    return new RangeOrValue(min.Value, max.Value);
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Missing min or max at path {0}", reader.Path));

            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid token type {0} at path {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
        }
    }
}
```

Using the extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static int ValueAsInt32(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Integer)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Value is not Int32");
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Wrap the system exception in a serialization exception.
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid integer value {0}", reader.Value), ex);
        }
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Comment)
                return reader;
        }
        throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexpected end at path {0}", reader.Path));
    }

    public static JsonReader MoveToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
            if (!reader.Read())
                return reader;
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }
}
```

However, if you're willing to pay a slight performance penalty, the converter can be simplified by serializing and deserializing a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) as shown below, which uses the same extension method class:

```
public class RangeOrValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    class RangeDTO
    {
        public int Min, Max;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(RangeOrValue) || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) == typeof(RangeOrValue);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var range = (RangeOrValue)value;
        if (range.IsRange)
        {
            var dto = new RangeDTO { Min = range.Min, Max = range.Max };
            serializer.Serialize(writer, dto);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(range.Value);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContent().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                // nullable RangeOrValue; return null.
                return null;

            case JsonToken.Integer:
                return new RangeOrValue(reader.ValueAsInt32());

            default:
                var dto = serializer.Deserialize<RangeDTO>(reader);
                return new RangeOrValue(dto.Min, dto.Max);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle showing both converters [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBdmR8).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. But I'm getting `Cannot access internal method 'MoveToContent' here`. I'm using Json.Net 12.0.1 via NuGet in .Net Core 2.1 project. How can I solve this?

Comment: @MoNarimani - `MoveToContent()`  is in the extension method class `JsonExtensions` in the first part of the answer.